# Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization after webpack5 build

Tags: javascript, webpack-5, angular14, angular14upgrade, angular-webpack

I'm using Angular 14 and Webpack version: `^5.58.1`.

Below is the config:

**webpack.congif.js**

```js
const webpackPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularWebpackPlugin;
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: {
    main: "./js/main.js",
    mainDrawer: "./js/divdrawer/main.ts",
    polyfills: "./js/divdrawer/polyfills.ts",
    entry: "./js/entry.js",
    thirdpartylibs: "./js/thirdpartylibs.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build/"),
    filename: "[name]bundle.js"
  },

module: {
    rules: [
      {
        parser: {
          system: true,
        }
      }
        test : /\.(tsx|ts)$/,
        use: [
               {
                 loader: '@ngtools/webpack',
                 options: {
                     configFile: path.resolve('./js/tsconfig.json')
                    },
               },
        ]
      },
    },

plugins: [
    new webpackPlugin({
      tsconfig: './js/tsconfig.json',
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/,
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./js/divdrawer")
    )
  ]
}
```

While generating the build I'm getting below error:

```
ERROR in ./js/divdrawer/filterMappingRemover.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
    at D:\MyProject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
 @ ./js/entry.js 10:30-97

ERROR in ./js/divdrawer/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
    at D:\MyProject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

ERROR in ./js/divdrawer/polyfills.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
    at D:\MyProject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18

ERROR in ./js/divdrawer/renderer.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
    at D:\MyProject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
 @ ./js/entry.js 9:18-61
```

All the entries are throwing errors in the message above. As mentioned in the Webpack config we have multiple entries.

This is detected when I upgraded our project to Angular 14 (Angular upgrade Steps: v10 --> v11--> v12--> v13/v14).

How to configure AngularWebpackPlugin correctly? Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Srihari I resolved it by downgrading my version of typescript.  I noticed a typescript version too high error further down in the console, so I ran this command:  `npm i typescript@">=4.8.2 < 4.9.0"`

Comment: But why this error is creeping...

Comment: No. Downgrading typescript version to 4.8.2 not resolving this issue.

Answer (score 15):

For me this solution worked:

go to package.json and change your typescript version, If you want to upgrade your angular project to

**Angular 15 (npm install typescript@"~4.8.0"  --save-dev)**

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.8.0"
}
```

**Angular 14 (npm install typescript@"~4.7.0"  --save-dev)**

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.7.0"
}
```

Credit to [F.R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9606851/f-r)

Answer (score 2):

yes downgrading typescript version to 4.8.2 resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error message while upgrading from Angular 14 -> 15. However, another error was also logged:

> Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.6.2 and <4.8.0 but 4.8.2 was found instead.

My `package.json` indicated version `15` for most `@angular` packages, but somehow `@angular/compiler-cli` was still set to `14`.

Changing it to `15` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, upgrading node version 16.xx to 18.xx (LTS) fixed the issue.

Comment: didn't work. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues and realized they were due node-sass fail on installation due to lacking build essentials in my ubuntu installation. i solved it by running this command in ubuntu

```html
sudo apt update && apt install build-essential
```

If you are using Windows and npm, install it through cmd (Administrator):

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
ng update @angular/core@14
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I verified read and write access on *node_modules* folder and it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34950541)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error when I was experimenting moving a file around and ending up with something like this in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"],
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/some-folder/some-subfolder/another-subfolder/the-file.ts",
    "src/some-folder/some-subfolder/the-file.ts"
  ],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

[image]

Removing the duplicate file gets rid of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a specific version could solve this issue.
E.g. "typescript": "^5.1.6" => "typescript": "5.1.6"

Perhaps something wrong with typescript version 5.2.2, which my application tries to create a dependency to.